# How can i make it draw a rectangle with dots?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After 2 hours of looking for answer i have given up. Right now i'm getting lines of dots, but i want it to be a rectangle. I want this to print rectangle which length and width are input by the user.

```
print("Insert width:")
width_number= int(input())
print("Insert length:")
length_number = int(input())

for length in range(length_number):
    for width in range(width_number):
        print("* "* width, end="")
    print("* " * width)
    print()
```

Expected output:

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the input, the expected output, and the actual output? Are you getting any errors? If so, what is the full text of them? Please [edit] your question and put the information into it, otherwise this may be closed as "Unclear what you're asking" or "Too Broad."

Comment: You haven't asked a question other than, "please gibe codes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print  `*` times the width at the beginning and end. Print two `"*"` with width - 2 times spaces betweem

```
print("*" * width_number)
for _ in range(length_number):
    print("*" + (" " * (width_number-2)+ "*") )
print("*" * width_number)
```

You can also use `str.format`:

```
print("*" * width_number)   
for _ in range(length_number):
    print("*{:^{fill}}*".format(" ",fill=width_number-2))
print("*" * width_number)


Insert width:
10
Insert length:
10
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out so fast :) Saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: @MihkelKull, no worries, you could get more creative with the loops but this method is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
print("Insert width:")
width_number= int(input())
print("Insert length:")
length_number = int(input())
print("* "*width_number)
for length in range(length_number - 2):
    print("* ", end="")
    for width in range(width_number - 2):
        print("  ", end="")
    print("* ")
print("* "*width_number)
```

If you want spaces in between your *